# I can't access my SD-Card in my F:/ directory because of missing admin rights, how can I change this with the command prompt?

Tags: cmd, windows-10, command, admin, sd-card

I start the command prompt with adimn rights and run this code

`icacls "F:\" /q /c /t /grant Users:F`

Unfortunately this does not work. I get the following error message

The syntax for the file name, directory name, or volume label is incorrect.
0 files processed successfully, a processing error occurred with 1 files.

Can someone please help me out? I also tried the way with Security Register and adding a new user with full permission on this directory but this did not work either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing the quotes or use `"F:\."`; I suspect that `icacls` might use the `\ `as an escape character…

Comment: SD cards are normally FAT so the command will never work.

Comment: Good point, @user14122392, but would the command report a syntax error then?